# Excel Match last Word in all Strings in a Range...VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, vlookup

I am creating a little tool that helps analyze song writing techniques.
I have a database with this year's song lyrics in Col. A.
The lyrics go downward line by line (example)

```
1. You’re so indecisive of what I’m saying
1. Tryna catch the beat, make up your heart
1. Don't know if you're happy or complaining
1. Don't want for us to end, where do I start?
1. First you wanna go to the left then you wanna turn right
1. Wanna argue all day, making love all night
1. First you're up then you’re down and in between*
```

I would like to create a vba that calls a user to input a word...for example 
"Start" in this case.
The code would match the last word of each sentence and return the columns containing the searched word as the last word in the sentence.

It would then need to display a message to the user with the entire sentence, as well as two sentences above and two sentences below.

IN our example it would bring back the sentences below back to user:

```
1. Tryna catch the beat, make up your heart
1. Don't know if you're happy or complaining
1. Don't want for us to end, where do I start?
1. First you wanna go to the left then you wanna turn right
1. Wanna argue all day, making love all night
```

I wrestled between V-Lookups and Index-Match but are having trouble finding a good place to start.

Does anyone have an pointers of could direct me on the right path?

UPDATE:

I do not have a working code yet. What I have are formulas in the worksheet

In column B,

I have the formula

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND(" ",A4)),"",RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A4," ","*",LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4," ",""))))))
```

Which documents the last work of each sentence

in Column D,

I have a formula that compares an input word, with column B, and bring back column A

```
=IF($D$2=B4,A4,"NO MATCH")
```

I believe I can possibly write a VBA that can replace "D2" with the search word, but then I am stuck on how I would proceeded from there

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tPNJ.png

Comment: Can you post the current code you have to try to do this, and which I suppose is failing ?

Comment: Please see update on original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GENERAL APPROACH**

You need to breakdown your issue into composable steps:

- Issue 1. get the value (string) to analyze
- Issue 2. find all the occurences of a single value into a column
- Issue 3. for one given row, show the neighbouring two rows (up and down)

If you can solve each problem individually, you just have to compose somehow the solution to get what you are eventually looking for.

**VBA vs. plain excel formulas**

If you don't have stringent requirements for ergonomy, you can do a lot of what you want just with excel formula. But if you have/need a user-interface, VBA is the best choice.  So if you have good, even average VBA skills then go that road, because the formula road requires excellent knowledge of a large range of excel formulas.

**SOLVING THE ISSUES**

Once you have this breakdown, you can google it (or post it on SO - you will get more answers if you have a small easily understandable issue).

For instance, I google issue 2, I found (among other things):

1. http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119:vlookup-multiple-values-return-multiple-corresponding-values-for-one-lookup-value&catid=77&Itemid=473

This is a regular excel formula that solves the issue 2 (have special look at step 3, this is what you need for the issue 3, the index of the found value). It is also explained in detail how the formula works. Even if you pursue the VBA route, you can still reuse the formula in your VBA code so it is all good.

Now you want the value to be found to be the last word in your sentences. So add a column which will hold the last word of your sentence, and apply solution 2 to that column.

Issue 3 is also solvable through formula, once you have the index to start from. You might have to use the following function `OFFSET` and array formulas. For array formulas, see: http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html. If what I just said is chinese to you, go the VBA road, it will be easier.

I don't give you a solution (sorry I am a bit busy) but I hope that at least this helps you to think around the problem and find solutions for smaller steps which compose into what you are looking for.

[UPDATE]:
After some googling, here is some solution you can improve on:

- Add the following user-defined functions to your excel sheet

`

```
Function concatFormat(Delimiter As Variant, ParamArray CellRanges() As Variant) As String
  Dim Index As Long, Rw As Long, Col As Long, Down As Boolean, Rng As Range, Cell As Range
  If IsMissing(Delimiter) Then Delimiter = ""
  Index = LBound(CellRanges)
  Do While Index <= UBound(CellRanges)
    If TypeName(CellRanges(Index)) = "Range" Then
      Set Rng = CellRanges(Index)
      If Index < UBound(CellRanges) Then
        If TypeName(CellRanges(Index + 1)) <> "Range" Then Down = CellRanges(Index + 1) = "|"
      End If
      If Down Then
        For Col = 0 To Rng.Columns.Count - 1
          For Rw = 0 To Rng.Rows.Count - 1
            If Len(Rng(1).Offset(Rw, Col).Value) Then concatFormat = concatFormat & Delimiter & Rng(1).Offset(Rw, Col).Text
          Next
        Next
        Index = Index + 1
      Else
        For Each Cell In Intersect(Rng, Rng.Parent.UsedRange)
          If Len(Cell.Value) Then concatFormat = concatFormat & Delimiter & Cell.Text
        Next
      End If
    Else
      If CellRanges(Index) = "||" Then
        concatFormat = concatFormat & Delimiter & "|"
      Else
        concatFormat = concatFormat & Delimiter & CellRanges(Index).Text
      End If
    End If
    Index = Index + 1
  Loop
  concatFormat = Mid(concatFormat, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
End Function

Function UStrip(sWord As String) As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim sCharacter As String
'This function takes a string outputs an uppercase equivalent with
'  all characters stripped but numbers and letters
'Uppercase is used since it is a better function with "Find" since case becomes immaterial
    sWord = UCase(sWord)  'Convert to Uppercase
    UStrip = "" 'Set originall as null
    For x = 1 To Len(sWord) 'Act on each letter
        sCharacter = Mid(sWord, x, 1)
        If Asc(sCharacter) >= 65 And _
            Asc(sCharacter) <= 90 Then '65-90 are ASCII "A"-"Z"
            'sCharacter is a LETTER
            UStrip = UStrip & sCharacter
        ElseIf sCharacter = " " Then
            'sCharacter is a space
            UStrip = UStrip & sCharacter
        ElseIf Asc(sCharacter) >= 48 And _
            Asc(sCharacter) <= 57 Then '48-57 are ASCII "0"-"9"
            'sCharacter is a "text-NUMBER"
            UStrip = UStrip & sCharacter
      End If
    Next x
End Function
```

`

Those functions are almost totally copy-pasted from:
http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/139774-Strip-out-punctuation-Excel-2003
http://www.excelfox.com/forum/f22/formatted-flexible-concatenation-function-582/
These I found after a google search.

Then your excel sheet has to be organized like this:

- Column A : the original sentences
- Column B : the last word of the column A
- Column C : column B without punctuation i.e. with formula `=+ustrip(B2)`
- Column D : the index of the word to be found : `=IF(C2=$B$10,ROW(),"")`. Note that $B$10 is the word you want to find i.e. `start` in your example
- Column E : the concatened rows you want : `=concatFormat(CHAR(10),OFFSET($A$2:$A$6,IF(D2-4<0,0,D2-4),0,5))`
- Column F : eliminating the error values : `=+IF(ISERROR(E2),"",E2)`

Note that in my example, the sentences start[image: sample solution] in row 2 (row 1 is field name). So adapt the formulas accordingly if you don't start in row 2.

From that you can do the VBA part that ask a user to enter a word, and write the VBA which goes to read and present the values in the column F.

Comment: Thank you. Your breakdown gives me a good starting point. I appreciate it.

Comment: forgot to mention than in my sample, I modified the first sentence to add start as the last word. That was in order to test border conditions. Also my excel is in spanish, I translated my formula to english, I hope I did not make any mistake while doing so. Basically, if there is any `;` left, replace it with a `,`. I can't test it in english with my version of excel

Comment: This is great. I am going to improve on it and let you know how it goes! Thank you so much!

Comment: sure. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: This code worked wonders,did a little tinkering and rearranging bu it worked flawlessly.thank you.